# Trim string based on certain characters

Tags: php, string, substring

I've got a string which goes something like `myString__sfsdfsf`

All I know is that there is a `__` somewhere in the string. Content of the string and number of characters is unknown.

I want to remove the `__` and all characters that follow so I am left with just `myString`. How can I achieve this using PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done in several ways. PHP has lots of string functions. You can pick one depending on your requirements. Here are some ways:

Use [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) and [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos):

```
$str = 'myString__sfsdfsf';
echo substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '__')); // => myString
```

Or use [`strtok()`](http://php.net/strtok):

```
echo strtok($str, '__'); // => myString
```

Or, maybe even [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode):

```
echo explode('__', $str)[0]; // => myString
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [strpos()](http://php.net/substr) and [substr()](http://php.net/substr):

```
$str = 'myString__sfsdfsf';
echo substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '__'));
```

This should be quite fast. However if you need something more fancy than that, you probably want to look into regular expressions, e.g. [preg_match()](http://php.net/preg_match).

Answer (score 0):

Use [list()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) and [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
list($string,) = explode('_', 'myString__sfsdfsf');
echo $string; // Outputs: myString
```

Answer (score 0):

A [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace) would also work
`$string = str_replace('__', '', $string);`

Ignore that, didn't read your question properly