# Extract a part of variable ending with dash "-"

Tags: php

I have a variable `$TYPE=K180M-2`

I need to "extract only the part until the dash (K180M) in a new variable.

How can I do it?

Comment: I'd advise looking at the PHP docs before you ask. Hell... you've even tagged the thing in the post: http://uk3.php.net/explode

Comment: There's a [whole host of functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) that you can use to do this task. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20840499/1438393) might get you started.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to do my best hours of reading for a lot of new stuff and my head just blocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try:

```
$arr=explode("-", $TYPE);
```

`$arr[0]` will give you the desired result.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend! It works great!
And the better part is that I can use also the arr[1],arr[2] and so on... 
I wish you all the best in the new year!

Comment: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" sorry.
I will do it as soon as I can

Comment: really you need an array to get this value when there are so many built in functions???

Comment: What do you mean? Give me example function that may work, please?

Comment: You can use the function i have mentioned in my answer. I dnt want you to select it as an answer but it might help you

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$newType = substr($TYPE, 0, stripos($TYPE, '-'));
?>
```

Will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode` :

```
<?php

$K180M = '45';

$TYPE = 'K180M-2';

$var = explode('-',$TYPE,2);

$$var[0]; // this is your new variable named $K180M

var_dump($$var[0]); // result 45
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a regular expression, use `preg_replace()`

```
// Delete the dash and anything following it:
$type_without_dash = preg_replace("/-.*/", "", $TYPE);
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply use
**`$value=strstr($TYPE,'-',TRUE);`**

Comment: any reason down voters???

Comment: This is working only from 5.3 and can't make issues on some hostings

Comment: @newman and where has user mentioned which version he is using. You should down vote if its a WRONG ANSWER. Not because the answer doesnot match the NON MENTIONED version.